# Share object between activities in Android

Tags: android, sharing, serializable

Here's my problem...

I have a class DataBaseHelper.java, which handles all the database operations (creates tables, inserts data, delete tables, select data, etc.) and I have an instance of that class in my main activity. What I want to do now is use that instance of DataBaseHelper in other activities...

Currently I have declared that DataBaseHelper implements Serializable:

```
public class DataBaseHelper implements Serializable{ ... }
```

so I can pass the instance using

```
intent.putExtra("key",dbh)
```

and receive it in the other activity using

```
DataBaseHelper db = (DataBaseHelper) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("key");
```

But when I test the app, I get this in the LogCat:

```
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704): java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = tian.proto.lib.DataBaseHelper)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1176)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1130)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:488)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1552)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:502)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:5623)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1341)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1374)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at tian.proto.Main$asyncLogin.onPostExecute(Main.java:207)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at tian.proto.Main$asyncLogin.onPostExecute(Main.java:1)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704): Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: tian.proto.Main
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1535)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1689)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1653)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:1143)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:413)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1241)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1575)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1689)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1653)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1171)
10-17 09:28:16.515: E/AndroidRuntime(2704):     ... 22 more
```

What am I doing wrong? Maybe this is not the correct way to share objects between activities? What can I do about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to serialize database helper?

Comment: Classes like this should probably be organized as singletones, as you'll probably need only one instance of DatabaseHelper in your application.

Answer (score 0):

this isn't what you intended, but if you want to share the instance of a class then putting it as a serialiable object might not be useful. What i suspect is that you'd want something like this in order to access all of the class' methods, etc

```
DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper(this);
```

try that in onCreate.

serializing objects are more for objects created or modified inside classes like arraylists or something (though a getter/setter method wold probably be more conventional and more useful)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried in this way?

```
Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
if(b!=null)
DatabaseHelper dh = (DatabaseHelper) b.getParcelable("key");
```

From the receiver part.

Comment: since WHEN is a DatabaseHelper Parcleable?

Comment: If i create a custom class, that implements Parcelable obviously, i don't know why this could be a problem.

Comment: Shure. But you never mentioned inside your post that one actally HAS to implement the Parcelable interface. Therefore Your example is either incomplete or will bring just bring up another Exception

Comment: Yeah, that's my fault. My answer was incomplete,it could be done only with an implementation of the Parcelable class